# Un synonyme pour la locution « quitte à »

Tags: mathématiques, locutions, synonymes

Je cherche un synonyme de la locution "Quitte à prendre" surtout dans un contexte mathématique, si quelqu'un pouvait m'aider à mieux le comprendre.

- Quitte à prendre :
- Quitte à échanger :
- Quitte à remplacer :
- Quitte à deviner:

[image]

[image]

[image]

J'ai consulté le site [Mediadico](http://www.notrefamille.com/dictionnaire/definition/quitte_a) qui donne la définition : « en prenant risque de ».

Comment: C'est vraiment un synonyme que tu cherche, ou une explication du sens ?

Comment: si possible les deux

Comment: Je trouve ce terme très familier personnellement. Plus de la bouche d'un professeur essayant d'expliquer un théorème ou autre, que sur un exo/cours écrit.

Comment: ouii mais je le comprend pas encore

Comment: @Larme: C'est tout à fait standard en mathématiques, c'est même du jargon technique. Une expression standard similaire cest *Sans perte de généralité, on peut supposer que …*, mais la raison doit être dans ce cas devinée.

Answer (score 4):

**La notion liée à cette formule est celle d'une conséquence possible à connotation négative: que l'on ne souhaite pas *en priorité*, mais que l'on accepterait.**

Il s'emploie souvent avec une principale au conditionnel, ou avec une possibilité.

C'est équivalent à:

> Avec l'inconvénient de + infinitif / substantif
>
> Avec la gêne de + infinitif / substantif

Les deux suivants sont plus forts et dépendent du contexte:

> Avec la contrainte de + infinitif / substantif
>
> En prenant le risque de + infinitif / substantif (avec l'article le)
>
> Au risque de + infinitif

Le [CNRTL](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/quitte) cite une autre forme, rare: *quitte pour*

quitte peut parfois être accordé (sur la même référence):

> Ils imaginèrent quelque chose de tout à fait ingénieux: se lancer à
>   la poursuite de leur argent! remettre, coûte que coûte, la main sur le
>   fuyard, **quittes** à refaire, de jour, la course folle de la nuit!

**Lorsque quitte à précède la principale, le sens peut être différent** et exprimer: *puisqu'on fait (doit faire) quelque chose, on peut aussi en profiter pour autre chose ou quelque chose de plus intéressant.*

On trouve souvent: *quitte à* ... *autant*

> Quitte à partir en vacances, autant aller au soleil => Puisqu'on part
>   en vacances, on peut aller au soleil.
>
> Quitte à remplacer le téléviseur, on peut acheter un écran plat.
>
> Quitte à travailler en plus, autant étudier quelque chose
>   d'intéressant.

Answer (score 3):

Dans ce contexte mathématique, il n'y a aucune notion de "risque" dans l'expression "quitte à" (je ne crois pas que mediadico a cet aspect mathématique en tête). Quand on dit :

> Quitte à faire X, on peut supposer Y

Cela signifie (en général) qu'avant cette phrase on avait des variables, des suppositions... plutôt libres, mais que quitte à faire des hypothèses un peu plus contraignantes (X) et à faire quelques manipulations, on peut supposer que Y est vrai. Je pense que le mieux est de regarder des exemples.

- Dans le premier example, j'imagine qu'il y avait l'intégrale d'une fonction entre a et b mais qu'on ne savait pas si a était plus petit que b ou non. Mais comme l'intégrale d'une fonction entre a et b est égale à l'opposé de l'intégrale entre b et a, on peut échanger les bornes d'intégration ; un signe "moins" va apparaître, mais ce n'est pas grave, car en manipulant un peu l'expression obtenue, on peut le faire disparaître.
- Dans le deuxième exemple, on sait qu'il existe un certain M vérifiant l'équation ; mais si M vérifie l'équation, alors M+1 aussi, et comme on a juste besoin que M vérifie l'équation, M+1 convient très bien aussi. Mais en prenant M+1 à la place de M, on est sûr qu'on a quelque chose de strictement positif.

C'est une expression à rapprocher de l'expression ["Sans perte de généralité"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans_perte_de_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ralit%C3%A9) qui apparaît souvent en mathématiques. Je pense que cette phrase de l'article explique bien "quitte à" aussi :

> Cette expression, généralement suivie par une supposition restrictive, indique que la démonstration se limite à un cas particulier, mais que les autres cas peuvent être établis par une démonstration analogue à celle du cas envisagé, ou même se ramener à ce cas.

Quand on dit

> Sans perte de généralité, on peut supposer Y

on fait exactement la même chose qu'avec "quitte à", mais le "quitte à" explique en plus comment se ramener au cas général une fois le cas particulier établi (en faisant X).

Answer (score -2):

en Français, on peut aussi utiliser le terme ''Quand''.
Ex: Quand à faire du bien .....
    Quand à déclarer que ......

Mais cela suppose que la phrase soit précédée d'une autre hypothèse ou d'une autre affirmation.

Comment: *Quant à* (avec un *t*) et *quitte à* ne signifient pas la même chose.